# echo two arrays dynamically in php

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, user-interface, model-view-controller

I want to print two array values dynamically like for every constant value the variable should change. there are 5 constant values like we do, we jockey, we create, we innovate, we sell and variable values are ideas,brands,creative,campaigns.

(Constant) we do (flip- vertical) ideas,brands,creative,campaigns
(Constant) we jockey  (flip- vertical)  ideas,brands,creative,campaigns

...

for every constant part the variable part has to change. where i am going wrong?
The code below prints properly but the constant part should not change.`

I am using this code:

```
<?php 
     $bikes=array("DO","JOCKEY","CREATE","INNOVATE","SELL");
     foreach ($bikes as $items) {
        $cars=array("IDEAS","BRANDS","CREATIVE","CAMPAIGNS");
        for($i=0;$i<10;$i++)
        {
           echo "  <a class='blue' style='text-decoration:none' href=''>WE $bikes[$i] $cars[$i]</a>";
        }
     }

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php 

    $bikes=array("DO","JOCKEY","CREATE","INNOVATE","SELL");
    $cars=array("IDEAS","BRANDS","CREATIVE","CAMPAIGNS");
    foreach ($bikes as $bike) {    
        foreach($cars as $car){
            echo "<a class='blue' style='text-decoration:none' href=''>WE ".$bike." ".$car."</a><br>";
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: i am using bootstrap. i am getting all the prints echoed. we do ideas, we do brands, we do creative.. and so on in a long list... i want to apply flip vertical. and "we" should be constant. 

    foreach ($bikes as $bike) {    
        foreach($cars as $car){
  

   
 echo " <div id='home'>";
     echo "<span class='tagline'>We";
       echo "<span class='tag-change'>";
         echo " <a class='active purple' href=''>".$bike." ".$car."</a>";
     
       echo"</span>";
     echo "</span>";
      


   
   
   
   
        }
    }
?>

Comment: for a flip vertical just change the order of values in $bikes manually : ) . I don't really get your other question.

Comment: echo "<span class='tagline'>We"; echo "<span class='tag-change'> should work to get flip effect. please see this demo. http://www.webdesigncrowd.com/demo/animated-taglines-7.21.14/flip-vertical.html

Comment: You want that same effect?! you need javascript.

Comment: yes same effect . but two words are changing . in the demo there is only one word that is changing

Comment: That is made with javascript. You cannot do that just printing the array values with php. Post a new question about making that effect, and I will try to respond. Upvote here please :)